# Two routers LAN-LAN connection. No internet on second

Tags: networking, router, lan

My main router/modem is connected to the internet. I have an old Linksys wag200g router I'd like to connect it to and run a simple server on it (thanks to the openwag firmware). It has no WAN port, only a LINE port and 4 LANs. I've set it to Bridge mode and connected it to the first. I've set its IP so that both routers are in the same network i.e. 192.168.1.x; I've disabled DHCP on it. They see each other but the second router can't access the internet (pinging e.g. 1.1.1.1 from it gives 100% packet loss). Is it possible to have internet on the linksys?

Comment: Are your clients on the linksys receiving ip addresses from the first router? If yes, Do the clients also have the first routers ip address as their default gateway?

Comment: *"It has no WAN port, only a LINE port and 4 LANs"* -- Because it is not just a *"router"* but also an *ADSL modem*.  The *"LINE port"* is for the phone connection.  *"the second router can't access the internet"* -- Are you somehow logged in to the Linksys?  Or do you mean some PC connected to the Linksys?  Connected how: Ethernet or WiFI?

Comment: I access the linksys via an SSH client run on my PC connected to the first router.